# Why does it render the same frame

Tags: modeling, animation

[image]

Im trying to make 360 degree turntable animation.When i hit play in layout it rotates,thats what i wanted but when i hit render Animation,it only renders the first frame.Here is for example the first and last frame[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to uncheck "Placeholders" and check "Overwrite" in your Output settings. If you have already rendered frames from any blend file, that is preventing new frames from being output to your tmp directory. After changing that, use "Render>Render Animation" to render the sequence, then "Render>View Animation to play the rendered sequence.

[image: Output Properties panel]

[image: Render menu]

Comment: Still doesnt work but i noticed something, the light rotates on the donut when i hit View animation

Comment: Are you not in Object mode when you hit the Render Animation button, or is there a modifier or an object/collection that has it's render visibility disabled? If you can attach the file that would help a lot, I need more information to make another suggestion.

Comment: Yeah i had to convert the particels and apply but now the sprinkles arent moving, should i Parent them to the Torus ?

Comment: Sounds like it.